# c++ function to merge bytes of 2 values

Tags: c++, merge, binary, byte, endianness

I want to be able to merge bytes from two unsigned long parameters, taking exactly half of the bytes, the half that starts with the least significant byte of the second param and the rest of the first param.

For example:

```
x = 0x89ABCDEF12893456 
y = 0x76543210ABCDEF19
result_merged = 0x89ABCDEFABCDEF19
```

First, I need to check whether the system that I work on is little endian or big endian. I already wrote a function that checks that, called **is_big_endian()**.

now I know that char `char *c = (char*) &y` will give me the "first"(MSB) or "last"(LSB)  (depends whether is big endian or not) byte of y.

Now, I do want to use AND(&) bitwise operator to merge x and y bytes, the question is how can I get only half of the bytes, starting from the LSB.

I mean I can use a "for" loop to go over size_of and then split by 2, but i'm confused how exactly should I do it.

And I also thought about "masking" the bytes, because I already know for sure that the given parameters are "long" which means 16 bits. so maybe I can mask them in the following way?

I want to be able to use it both on 32 and 64 bit systems, which means my code is wrong because i'm using here a fixed size of 64 bit long although I don't know what is the system that the code runs on.
I thought about using an array to store all the bits or maybe use shifting?

```
unsigned long merge_bytes(unsigned long x, unsigned long int y)
    {
    
     if (is_big_endian() ==0) {
    //little endian system
     return (y & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) | (x & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF);
           }
    else
        {
         return (y & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) | (x & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF); 
       }
    }
```

I have "masked" the right side of the bits if that's a little endian system because the LSB there is the furthest to the left bit.
And did the opposite if this is a big endian system.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to distinguish between little endian and big endian because you don't access memory.

Comment: But how would you know if the LSB is on the left or on the right? Because it's different on little & big endian bytes sorting.

Comment: Just FYI, if you can use C++20, there is now [std::endian](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian)

Comment: Endianess should not matter in this scenario as I believe the operators you are using are arithmetic. Small note, I would use a type with a defined size like `uint_fast64_t` so that your function is cross platform (since your masks appear to be 64bit)

Comment: @ColonD Hey, thanks. Although I still don't really understand why Endianness should not matter. I mean the LSB and MSB are located in different parts of the bytes sort in each of them.

Comment: @DimaCiun Let's say we are working in decimal, with the number 10, you write `int number = 10`. `number` holds `10`, it might be represented in memory as `000A`, or it might be represented in memory as `0A00` but it is still 10. The same applies for hexadecimal. `int number = 0x000A` does the exact same thing as before, but I have written the number in hexadecimal. It equals 10. It might be stored in memory as `000A` or `0A00`. It is the same number on both machines. That same number is being used on the same numbers in your function, no matter how the values are represented in memory.

Comment: @ColonD First of all thanks for the explanation, I appreciate it. Second, But.. and this is the question and sorry for repeating myself  - What does it have to do with LSB and MSB? I mean a big-endian system stores the most significant byte of a word at the smallest memory address and the least significant byte at the largest. A little-endian system, in contrast, stores the least-significant byte at the smallest address. So, I do need to determine where is the half that includes the MLS, and in order to do it, I need to check whether it's a big or a little endian machine.

Comment: @DimaCiun endianness is only relevant when you access the individual bytes of a  >8bit value in memory. You're not doing this in your code. And generally most code doesn't do this either.

Comment: You pretty much only need to deal with endianess when transferring data from one OS to another OS with a different endian, and if you are using any common operating system this will be little endian. Another scenario would be if you were using `reinterpret_cast` between an type and a byte array. Those are the only two scenarios I can think of in which you should worry about endianess.

Comment: @ColonD Hey, as you told me there are different sizes for "long" parameters in 32 bit and 64 bit systems. Which means I can't use a fixed size as I did. But I also can't use your suggestion and must use "long int" and not unit_fast64 (as part of the assignment requirements). Maybe I can store the bits in an array and then run a loop of them based on whether it's little or big endian?

Comment: @DimaCiun Are you allowed to use a `unsigned long long`? A byte in C++ has to be `>= 8` bits, and a `long long` has to be `>= 8` bytes, so it has to be at least `64` bits.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the signature of the function, which gets 2 unsigned long paraments. I think about using shifting or an array to store all the bits and then find the ones that  I need based on whether it's a big or little endian system.

Comment: I'm giving up here.

Comment: I have also helped all I can help. The function at minimum passes in two 32 bit values and at minimum returns a single 32 bit value. If you want to work on 64 bit numbers you will need to hope the compiler you use uses 64 bit `long`s. As for bit shifting, it also does not care about endianess. Using an array DOES care about endianess if you use `reinterpret_cast`, so be careful if you try something with that. Overall I do not think the way you create the returned value matters, the returns value is a `long` so it will be at least 32 bits no matter what you do in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. You want this:

```
merged = (y & 0x00000000ffffffff) | (x & 0xffffffff00000000);
```

There is no need to distinguish between big and little endian. The high bits of a value are the high bits of the value.

The difference is only the representation in memory.

**Example**: storage of the value `0x12345678` at memory location `0x0000`

Little endian:

```
Address  byte
-------------
0000     78
0001     56
0002     34
0003     12
```

Big endian:

```
Address  byte
-------------
0000     12
0001     34
0002     56
0003     78
```

Comment: Thanks alot  But(!) I did not understand your answer  to be honest and I would be glad if you'll try to explain me a little bit more. Will your code work on both Little and Big endian? are you sure? Becuase as I see it, you masked all the right half of the bits. But, what if that's a Little endian system, and  the right half is the right that we need because that's the LSB? We won't be able to use it because you masked it with zero's.

Comment: 0x00000000FFFFFFFF is the number 0x00000000FFFFFFFF on both big and little endian, they are stored differently in memory, but they are the same number

Comment: Yes, it will work on any architecture. I think you should ask another question just about this. Or start googling something like "big endian vs little endian", I'm sure something will show up

Comment: but the size of a "long" in a 32-bit system is not the same as "long" in a 64-bit system, and your code (and mine) are both giving fixed sized. (my friend just told me that)

Comment: @DimaCiun your code is obviously for 64 bit integers and so is mine. But anyway you can't store `0x89ABCDEF12893456 ` is a 32 bit `long`, so I don't get your comment.

Comment: If you want portable code, you should `#include <cstdint>` and use the `uint64_t` type which is guaranteed to be 64 bits on any platform.

Comment: I can't use any externals libraires, that's why I insisted on using big/little endian. Because this is the only way to make this code a portable one.

Comment: @DimaCiun huh? But `#include <cstdint>` _is_ form making portable code and it is not an external library but it's part of the C++ standard. I really don't get it. Please take a deep breath, lean back and think about what you _actually_ want to achieve. Then write an other all new question. Also read this: [ask] and maybe this: [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)